# How to loop through pandas and match a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Input table :
[image: Input table]

Output table :
[image: Output table]

I cant seem to figure it out.I need to group the columns with value 1 into a new column "New_column".  Can someone help me. This is the code that I have tried.

```
for (index_label, row_series) in data.iterrows():
print('Row Index label : ', index_label)
print('Row Content as Series : ', row_series.values)
```

Comment: Added performance test to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it with [dot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) :

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': [0,0,1],
        'B': [1,0,0],
        'C': [0,0,0,],
        'D': [1,0,1],
        'F': [1,0,1]
    }
)
df['new_column'] = df.dot(df.columns).str.join(",")



    A   B   C   D   F   new_column
0   0   1   0   1   1   B,D,F
1   0   0   0   0   0   
2   1   0   0   1   1   A,D,F
```

Update: For columns with more than one letter, @BEN_YO suggested a very good solution for that :

```
df.dot(df.columns+',').str[:-1]
```

Comment: Nice vectorized/non-loopy solution!

Comment: Added performance test to my answer and explains why your solution cannot tested, because cannot be used. OP has in real data [60 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63516639/how-to-loop-through-pandas-and-match-a-condition/63517029#comment112316330_63516788)

Comment: @sammywemmy you can do the fix :-) `df['new_column'] = df.dot(df.columns+',').str[:-1]
`

Comment: nice! I didnt bother since @jezrael had provided a pretty fast one, but this is good as well. I'll add it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If columns names has more like one character use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with add separator to columns names and last remove from right side by [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
df['new_column'] = df.dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(",")
#alternative
#df['new_column'] = (df @ (df.columns + ',')).str.rstrip(",")

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  F new_column
0  0  1  0  1  1      B,D,F
1  0  0  0  0  0           
2  1  0  0  1  1      A,D,F
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'col1': [0,0,1],
        'col2': [1,0,0],
        'col3': [0,0,0,],
        'col4': [1,0,1],
        'col5': [1,0,1]})


df['new_column'] = df.dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(",")
#alternative
#df['new_column'] = (df @ (df.columns + ',')).str.rstrip(",")

print (df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5      new_column
0     0     1     0     1     1  col2,col4,col5
1     0     0     0     0     0                
2     1     0     0     1     1  col1,col4,col5
```

Alternative solution:

```
cols = df.columns.to_numpy()
df["new_column"] = [', '.join(cols[x]) for x in df.to_numpy().astype(bool)]
```

**Performance**:

First solution from `sammywemmy` cannot be used, because 50 columns, so there are some columns with 2 or more letters. Also solution of `footfalcon` create lists, so also dont tested.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A': [0,0,1],
        'B': [1,0,0],
        'C': [0,0,0,],
        'D': [1,0,1],
        'E': [1,0,1]})

[30000 rows x 50 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 10, ignore_index=True, axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True).add_prefix('col')
```

Fastest is list comprehension solution, but only for 10ms in sample data, then are really fast `dot` solution and last are `apply` solutions:

```
In [70]: %%timeit
    ...: cols = df.columns.to_numpy()
    ...: df["new_column"] = [', '.join(cols[x]) for x in df.to_numpy().astype(bool)]
    ...: 
128 ms ± 443 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

#for testing are values converted to boolean (else test fail)
In [72]: %timeit df['new_column'] = df.astype(bool).dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(",")
138 ms ± 1.95 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

```
#Dishin H Goyani
In [73]: %timeit df["New_column"] = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(df.columns[x==1]), axis=1)
3.98 s ± 129 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#Akshay Sehgal
In [75]: %timeit df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(list(x[x!=0].index)), axis=1)
11 s ± 349 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#Rajith Thennakoon
In [78]: %%timeit
    ...: df["new_column"] = df.apply(lambda x: (pd.DataFrame(x[x==1]).index.values),axis=1)
    ...: df["new_column"] = df["new_column"].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))
    ...: 
    ...: 
25.9 s ± 709 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it gets the job done:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': [0,0,1],
        'B': [1,0,0],
        'C': [0,0,0,],
        'D': [1,0,1],
        'F': [1,0,1]
    }
)

df1 = df.T
new_cells = []
for c in df1.columns:
    new_cells.append(df1[df1[c] == 1].index.tolist())
df['New_column'] = new_cells
```

Output:

```
A   B   C   D   F   New_column
0   0   1   0   1   1   [B, D, F]
1   0   0   0   0   0   []
2   1   0   0   1   1   [A, D, F]
```

Comment: but is the solution practical? if we have 60 columns and thousand of rows??

Comment: Someone may post a better method, but this should still be fine for size of data you are dealing with.

Comment: Added performance test to my answer. Is possible create joined lists for add your solution to tests?

Comment: @jezrael I was just about to post the same. I tested on the dummy df as is. My shoddy solution came in at: 2.71 ms ± 91.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each).
sammywemmy's clocked: 1.22 ms ± 3.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[0,0,1],"B":[1,0,0],"C":[0,0,0],"D":[1,0,1],"F":[1,0,1]})

df["new_column"] = df.apply(lambda x: (pd.DataFrame(x[x==1]).index.values),axis=1)
df["new_column"] = df["new_column"].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))
```

output

```
   A  B  C  D  F new_column
0  0  1  0  1  1      B,D,F
1  0  0  0  0  0           
2  1  0  0  1  1      A,D,F
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` with `lambda` function on `axis=1`

```
df["New_column"] = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(df.columns[x==1]), axis=1)
df
   A  B  C  D  F New_column
0  0  1  0  1  1      B,D,F
1  0  0  0  0  0
2  1  0  0  1  1      A,D,F
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have python >= 3.5, you can use the matmul operator to do a [dot product](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) as -

```
df['new_column'] = (df @ df.columns).str.join(', ')
```

```
   A  B  C  D  E new_column
0  0  1  0  1  1    B, D, E
1  0  0  0  0  0           
2  1  0  0  1  1    A, D, E
```

---

Or you could use `apply` to solve this over axis=1 as following -

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(list(x[x!=0].index)), axis=1)
```

```
   A  B  C  D  E new_column
0  0  1  0  1  1    B, D, E
1  0  0  0  0  0           
2  1  0  0  1  1    A, D, E
```